# Prevent ftp_nlist from returning ".." and "."

Tags: php, ftp

I'm making this script in PHP that goes through all files in a specified folder on an external FTP server, downloads them, and puts them in a Zip file.

I'm using the 'ftp_nlist()' function for this, however the returned array always contains two extra elements, being ".." and "." ; I guess they represent the parent and current directory

My question was, how can I get rid of this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not big on FTP but a simple unset($array['where_ever_they_appear']); seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you cant. You should just ignore those indexes while using array data or iterate through array and unset them like this:

```
$list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '.');
foreach ($list as $key => $item) {
  if (in_array($item, array('.', '..'))) {
     unset($list[$key]);
  }
}
```